# How to build two different Docker Images with the same Jenkins Pipeline at the same the same build time?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Let's say my repository will have two different docker configuration files. Whenever one file will be update it will trigger Jenkins to build docker image. My challenge is if both files will be update, then Jenkins build will need to build two Docker images. What will be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: If you use the same cache, a build will be a an empty operation if it hasn't changed. so you could just build both every time

Comment: If the only thing that's changing is an application configuration file, also consider running only one image and injecting the configuration file with a `docker run -v` bind-mount option.

Comment: thanks guys for suggestions